# counting rows that date hasn't yet passed

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1111

I am trying to count the number of rows whose date has not yet passed so i can get only the current records

I get an error sayng

> MySQL error #111 Invalid use of group function

```
SELECT COUNT(festivalid) FROM festivals WHERE min(datefrom) > now()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you can not use aggregate (IE: MIN, MAX, COUNT...) functions in the `WHERE` clause - only in the `HAVING` clause can you do this.  And to define the `HAVING` clause, your query needs to have a `GROUP BY` clause defined:

```
  SELECT COUNT(f.festivalid)
    FROM FESTIVALS f
GROUP BY ? --festivalid would NOT be an ideal choice
  HAVING MIN(datefrom) > now()
```

...but I have my doubts about the query, and think it would be better to use:

```
SELECT COUNT(f.festivalid) 
  FROM FESTIVALS f
 WHERE f.datefrom > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is ANSI standard equivalent to MySQL specific `NOW()`, making the query portable to other databases.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COUNT(festivalid) 
FROM festivals 
WHERE datefrom > now()
```

Don't use the min function. That selects the minimum date which is not what you are looking for.

The min function is normally used as follows

```
SELECT MIN(dateFrom) FROM festivals
```

Answer (score 3):

don't use MIN...

```
SELECT COUNT(festivalid) FROM festivals WHERE datefrom > now()
```